# How do I use Find/Replace with a backreference followed by a number?

Tags: automation, text-editor, replace, backreference, komodoedit

I want to do a find/replace on the string matching `(abcdefg)1` with `\12`, but it doesn't work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a leading zero to the backreference:

```
\012
```

**References**

- [Example: Regular Expression Matching a Valid Date](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html)
- [How do you get a literal digit after a backreference in the *search* pattern](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bbedit/o936Qla2IF0)

Comment: Thanks! Had the same issue with replacement backreferences ($1), zero helps as well when the backreference is followed by a number (e.g. $0142 will use the first reference followed by 42).

Comment: @Vlad, good to know I'm not the only one facing this issue. Glad you found another use for it as well.